# Is there a general rule on what fields in linq to sql to have the UpdateCheck set to never?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have a field in my dbml file and when I try to update it, it gives me an error saying that the row or data has been changed.  I read that a solution would be to change the field's update check to never, but I am unclear on what this actually means.  All I have read is that Linq To Sql uses optimistic concurrency for updates and deletes, but I am unclear on what this means as well.  A good example would be nice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq-To-Sql resolves the concurrency problem by checking the old and current value of updated field. If there is a difference, an exception will be thrown. It's impossible for some db types such as Text and Image. Thus, you have to set the `UpdateCheck` property to `Never`. Check the following article for more information.

http://blogs.msdn.com/matt/archive/2008/05/22/into-to-linq-to-sql-optimistic-concurrency.aspx

Comment: In my particular situation, a smalldatetime field is causing the problem.